# Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.Web, Version=5.2.5.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, gac, machine.config

I am running a project sent by someone and its giving me this error:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.Web, Version=5.2.5.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' or one of its dependencies. 
The system cannot find the file specified
```

Here is the screenshot as well:

[image: error]

Can anybody help me, how to solve this error.

Comment: You are missing MySQL connector, download it from [this](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/1.0.html) link and install it or you can copy `MySql.Web.dll` and `MySql.dll` to your bin folder.

Comment: @Habib any version of connector will work?

Comment: No, only the one you have references. You can download the latest one , and update your reference in visual studio to the latest ones. Hopefully there won't be any breaking changes in your code. So this should fix it too. But remember to update the reference.

Comment: Any version should work (grab the most recent). You may have to update the version and/or public key token in the web.config, but you for sure must place the assemblies on the server in the bin as @Habib said.

Comment: its giving me error form machine.config

Comment: Thanks for the response,  it worked after installing mysql connector